# XMPP client library for ios with BOSH support

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am looking for a Objective C XMPP client library with BOSH support for my iPad app. I came across XMPPFramework but I learned that it does not have BOSH support or does it?

Can any one point me to some library or how i can use XMPPFrameWork with BOSH support?

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to find one for my project utilizing Jabber/XMPP so I ended up using [libstrophe](http://strophe.im) for my project. It works perfectly, if you need an Objective-C object, you can simply wrap the method calls with senders and receivers.

Comment: thanks for the reply,but does libstrophe have BOSH implementation ? it seems i only will have to add BOSH support according to this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/libstrophe/bJqdvKUc_og)

Comment: i started compiling libstrophe into a static library and i am facing some issues ,some of the header files are not found for eg:<gnutls/gnutls.h>,security.h,check.h.Did u face similar issues ? how did u solve dem?

Comment: @Suhas_United, Sounds like you need to link in the gnutls framework, found [here](http://www.gnutls.org).

Comment: I am trying to add gnutls for ios found [here](https://github.com/x2on/GnuTLS-for-iOS), is this what you are using or how did u add gnutls framework.Can you pls provide more details.